# Java - Design Pattern, Session Management for Web Service Client

Tags: java, design-patterns, reference

I am writing a client library for a web service using CXF. The service uses a mutable key to manage sessions and, optionally, allows a session to be kept alive.

I have built a client `Client` and I want to provide the ability for uses of the library to choose their type of session management i.e. either a manager which just manages keys but does not attempt to keep alive and a manager which manages keys and keeps the session alive.

I had thought of having a `SessionManager` field in the `Client` class (with a `SimpleSessionManager` class and a `KeepAliveSessionManager` class) but, in order to keep the session alive, the `KeepAliveSessionManger` would have to call a method of the `Client` class. That would mean that the `Client` class has a reference to the `SessionManager` class and the `SessionManager` class would have a reference to the `Client` class - which is obviously an inelegant design.

Can you suggest a design pattern (or altnernate implementation) that would let me implement these features in a 'better' way?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SessionManager as a factory for "clients" that would return an interface for the client.
The client wouldn't need to "know" the SessionManager. And if the SessionMaAnager was a KeepAliveSessionMaanger, it would internally keep the session alive.

Something like this:

```
SessionManager sm = new KeepAliveSessionManager(int keepAliveTimeout);

IClient client = sm.GetClient();
client.InvokeSomeMethod();
```

The SessionManager internally uses a thread (or something) and the client to keep the session alive. The client never "knows" about the SessionManager..

BTW, i'm thinking in .NET but it should translate to java...